# Private method overriding and visibility

Tags: php, oop, visibility, overriding

I'm having a hard time trying to understand the output of the following code:

```
class Bar 
{
    public function test() {
        $this->testPublic();
        $this->testPrivate();
    }

    public function testPublic() {
        echo "Bar::testPublic\n";
    }

    private function testPrivate() {
        echo "Bar::testPrivate\n";
    }
}

class Foo extends Bar 
{
    public function testPublic() {
        echo "Foo::testPublic\n";
    }

    private function testPrivate() {
        echo "Foo::testPrivate\n";
    }
}

$myFoo = new foo();
$myFoo->test();
```

Output:

```
Foo::testPublic
Bar::testPrivate
```

Class *Foo* overrides *testPublic()* and *testPrivate()*, and inherits *test()*. When I call *test()*, there is an explicit instruction envolving *$this* pseudo variable, so after I created *$myFoo* instance, the final calls of *test()* function would be *$myFoo->testPublic()* and *$myFoo->testPrivate()*. The first output is as I expected, since I overrode *testPublic()* method to echo *Foo::testPublic*. But the second output makes no sense to me. Why is it *Bar::testPrivate* if I overrode *testPrivate()* method? Also the private method from parent class wouldn't be inherited anyway, by definition! It makes no sense. Why is the parent method the one being called???

Comment: Consider changing `public function test() {
        $this->testPublic();
        $this->testPrivate();
    }` to `public function test() {
        $this->testPublic();
        static::testPrivate();
    }` - then read about [late static binding](http://www.php.net/lsb) (particularly Example #3)

Comment: @MarkBaker these methods are called in object context, not static, therefore late static binding does not apply. This was a simple visibility issue.

Comment: @rainfromheaven - I did specifically reference __Example #3__  in my comment, "static:: usage in a __non-static__ context".... i.e. in an __object__ contect. Late static binding applies exactly as stated in that part of the docs

Comment: @MarkBaker I retract my previous statement, you were right about the late static binding :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the method `Bar::testPrivate` is `private`, therefore it cannot be overridden by child classes. For starters, I recommend that you read up on visibility in PHP - http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php. There you will learn that only `public` and `protected` class member methods/properties can be overridden, `private` ones cannot.

As a good example, try changing the visibility of the `Bar::testPrivate` method to either public or protected, without altering anything else in your example code. Now try and run your tests. What happens? This:

> PHP Fatal error:  Access level to Foo::testPrivate() must be protected (as in class Bar) or weaker

The big question is: "why?". Well, you have now overridden `Bar::testPrivate` with a private `Foo:testPrivate`. This new private method is out of scope for `Bar::test`, because private class members are visible to their current class only, **NOT** the parent/child classes!

Therefore, as you can see, OOP provides a certain amount of encapsulation for class members, and it can be quite confusing if you don't take the time to understand it.

Comment: Believe it or not, the code I posted is from the link you suggested, PHP official manual, concerning the visibility part. It's part of Example #2.

Comment: Yes, and while that example lacks an explanation of what it does, it actually illustrates what `private` visibility means in terms of method overriding (that it **cannot** be done).

Comment: Oh, I understand it now. But I have another question then. A "protected" method should not be able to be accessed from other objetcs, but this way it's been accessed, right? It's like a workaround to call a protected method. Isn't it breaking encapsulation?

Comment: No, it doesn't break encapsulation in any way, as that is how it was designed to be. Protected class members can be accessed by parent/child classes when they are instances of the same class (i.e. you are extending the class with the protected members). PS: it's customary to choose an answer if it fulfills your needs