# PHP Object Oriented Programming Oops Issues

Tags: php, oop, object, inheritance

I am trying to implement a code somewhat like below but not able to understand one issue, as per my understanding it should have printed the data like this:

```
Foo::testPrivate
Foo::testPublic
```

But its displaying output as ::

```
Bar::testPrivate 
Foo::testPublic
```

The code is::

```
class Bar 
{
    public function test() {
        $this->testPrivate();
        $this->testPublic();
    }

    public function testPublic() {
        echo "Bar::testPublic\n";
    }

    private function testPrivate() {
        echo "Bar::testPrivate\n";
    }
}

class Foo extends Bar 
{
    public function testPublic() {
        echo "Foo::testPublic\n";
    }

    private function testPrivate() {
        echo "Foo::testPrivate\n";
    }
}

$myFoo = new Foo();
$myFoo->test();
```

Can somebody please explain this?

Comment: The edited returns `Bar::testPrivate Foo::testPublic`

Comment: A child cannot overwrite private function.

Comment: The docs: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: Calling "$this->testPrivate()" at the parent class defined method, proceed the parent private method testPrivate if it is defined (by definition they cant be overwritten). If it is protected or public it will try to proceed the child class methods first (if its defined, else it will look into the parent for existing one)..

Comment: Found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654055/private-method-overriding-and-visibility

Answer (score 0):

As per my Understanding

- Displaying output is right because of you are created object of "Foo" class and then after call test() function is inside the "Bar" class
- In test() function of Bar class is call testPrivate() using "this" keyword so call the function in same class and testPrivate() is also private so that's why display result like :

**Bar::testPrivate 

Foo::testPublic**

- Make changes to **private function testPrivate()** { } to **public function testPrivate()** in both the class for displayed your accepted result
- Result after made this changes is :

**Foo::testPrivate
 
Foo::testPublic**